# How to properly subclass UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableViewController` in which I defined some specific cell properties in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  The only method I actually defined anything specific was the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  I didn't include any other methods.  (so essentially the UITableViewController is empty aside from cellForRowAtIndexPath)

Now, I am attempting to subclass based on this UITableViewController, but my question is how do I set up the cellForRowAtIndexPath for the sublcass?  If I leave it blank, the app crashes because it expects a cell to be defined.  However, shouldn't it be using the cell defined in the base class?

What exactly do I have to put in my subclass' cellForRowAtIndexPath method to use the cell settings i created in my base class?

*edit* I have been told the solution, and for anyone wondering, you call the super's class inside your subclass with something like

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
```

this returns the super's cell to your sublcass, and then you return that cell.

Comment: To see good patterns for how to do what you're trying to do, do a File/New Class from XCode, and ensure you are picking UITableViewController as the class you're subclassing. XCode will start you off with a good template which shows you most of what you'll need to know.

Comment: What was the feature you have implemented in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? You should subclass `UITableViewCell` and implement these features inside that if it is specific to the table view cell.

Comment: @James that is exactly what i did during the setup process.

Comment: @ACB i am creating a cell of a type that is a subclass of a UITableViewCell

Comment: @JesseDurham - so you're trying to figure out how to get an instance of your custom UITableViewCell returned then? If you're doing this all through code, you'll want to take a look at the docs for UITableView's `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method. That will allow you to bind a your custom tableviewcell class to a given reuse ID..

Comment: I was under the impression when you set values/objects/components in a base class, any subclasses you create would also have those objects.  I'm simply trying to set my cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath in my base tableview to be a specific cell subclass.  Then, when i create any subclasses from the base tableview, they also have the specific cell subclass.  The problem is I dont know how to declare, or what to put in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of my subclasses.

Comment: @JesseDurham - To me, it seems like you're doing something odd. Regardless, if your question was "How do I call a method of a superclass", then yes, you now have the right answer. If I may ask, what is your subclass doing that your superclass isn't?

Answer (score 1):

This method is a required part of the table view data source protocol, which you need to specify. If you look at the developer documentation for UITableViewController, you'll see cellForRowAtIndexPAth isn't a function of it; it's under the UITableViewDataSource [which you can find here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource). This means, there's no implementation in the base class; the functions are abstract in the protocol and you're supposed to extend them and implement them.

You can return empty cells instead if you plan on creating an empty table. Just allocate them and return them in the function; subclassing the table view cells isn't required. Once your app stops crashing, you can specify the text you need. Use the indexPath to make the cells of different sections or different rows specify different text.

Comment: I see what you are saying.. so is there no way to inherit the properties I set for cells in my base class into the subclass?

Comment: Can you show me the custom classes that you created and what they inherit? You can find all those in the .h file declarations. They look like `@interface CustomTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: My sublcass is simply initialized as `@interface MySubClass : BaseClassTableView` I haven't done anything else.

Comment: you're confusing me a bit. Can you edit the question and include source code of the function cellForRowAtIndexPath so I know what's wrong?

Comment: I found the solution.  Basically, you have to call the super's method and return its value inside your sublcass' method.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly, you have a custom `UITableViewCell` you want to use in your implementation of `tableview:cellFowRowAtIndexPath:`.

You need to call `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`with you custom class AND the reuse identifier defined in `tableview:cellFowRowAtIndexPath:` to make it return an instance of this class.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

dont forget to call `#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing inheritance and delegation. Keep in mind that a `UITableView` needs a class to be it's `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. This class does not need to inherit from `UITableView`. I think what you'll have a better shot at what you're trying to do by subclassing a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I plan to add other features of the base class to be inherited to sublcasses which is why i didn't subclass the cell.  this was just a first step to see if I am doing it properly, which I am not.  And in fact, the change in my base class is altering the cell to a subclassed cell.

Comment: How about subclassing UIViewController - this would be your delegate and datasource and would also hold a reference to the table view.

Comment: because I want a subclass of my base UITableViewController not a UIViewController.  If I made a UIViewController and just added a TableView to it, i'd be in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that your UITableViewController - which contains cellForRowAtIndexPath is actually *already* a subclass of UITableViewController. It's header will look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

What distinguishes a UITableViewController is

- it has a self.tableView property that holds a reference to it's tableView.
- it adds two further properties and one method to the usual UIViewController superclass, but more importantly...
- it (usually) acts as the delegate and data source for the tableView

The latter means that it has to implement at least two datasource methods. As delegate methods, these are *not* implemented in the UITableViewController superclass, so  both have to be included:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

You have implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but you also need to implement numberOfRowsInSection: so that the table knows how large it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, these methods are in my base class.  But this doesn't reaaaaally deal with my question

Comment: @JesseDurham - sorry, I realised as I answered the question I hadn't quite got it right... Does your superclass work ok? I.e. you have _both_ the required methods there and the tableView works if you feed it some dummy data? Are you using storyboard or xib? Is the storyboard or Xib custom-classed to your tableVC subclass? Have you got your cell identifier in there OK? What exactly does the crash tell you is wrong?